# changing y axis values

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

How do you change the y axis points to letters? Specifically I'm interested in using musical notes in the y axis.

This is what I've tried and I received an error.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick={-A$\flat$, -A, -B$\flat$, -B, -C, C, C$\sharp$, D, D$\sharp$, E},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5]
\addplot [mark=none,domain=-4:4] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `yticklabels` (page 282) to define which labels do you want in each `ytick`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
  yticklabels={-A$\flat$, -A, -B$\flat$, -B, -C, C, C$\sharp$, D, D$\sharp$, E},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5]
\addplot [mark=none,domain=-4:4] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: now that I've added all the ticks the graph still comes out really small. How do I get the graph to take up the entire page?

Comment: @Marcus   You can add `width=\textwidth` in `axis` options to produce a plot as wide as text. It keeps plot proportions, but you can also add some fixed `height=...`. If you have the plot in an independent file you can enlarge it with `\includegraphics` options. In this case, text will be also scaled accordingly.

Comment: how can I now show plotted points with this new y axis. For example how would I plot (1, C)?

Comment: @Marcus I think you'll have to use real coordinates, labels are just labels. C=0, B=-2, E=4, ... May be someone can help you with a translation function, I cannot. You can write a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117).

Comment: You were correct. labels are just labels and real coordinates work just fine! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ytick` key sets the numerical points where the ticks should be created (unless you want to have symbolic coordinates though even then they are mapped to integers anyway). You would like to change the tick *label*s

Hence replacing the ytick option with below shows you as you wanted. Notice the number of integers matches the number of labels you have provided.

```
ytick={-5,...,5},
yticklabels={-A$\flat$, -A, -B$\flat$, -B, -C, C, C$\sharp$, D, D$\sharp$, E},
```

[image]